# Laravel 5.4 Sessions and Auth::user() not available in controller's constructor

Tags: laravel, authentication

I would like to use a User class throught the application. So, I would like to create CustomUser and then inject it into controllers that need it (it would be most of them).

Now, I create an empty instance in serviceprovider. Next, I want to fill it with data that are already saved in Auth::user(). After long time I have not found where to do it.

Auth::user() is empty in middlewares, but is filled with the user data in controllers. I am missing the step where Laravel queries the database and fills Auth:user() with data. I want to avoid making the same query again.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can try create base controller with property ```$user``` and set it in the ```__constructor()```. For example: ```public function __constructor{ $this->user = Auth::user(); }```

Comment: Andrey, I have tried that. Auth::user() is empty in "class Controller extends BaseController".  Each controller then extends Controller class, and it already contains the data. The Auth::user is filled somewhere in between.

Comment: No, no... ```Auth::user()``` work fine anywhere. If it empty maybe problem in the authorization system.

Comment: It seems that it is empty in Controller constructors. Methods called from the router work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.3, you do not have access to `sessions` in controller constructors. This is because the middleware has not been run yet. I know it's difficult to locate, but in the migration documentation from 5.2 > 5.3 (you're probably on 5.4), it shows that the proper way to resolve data from sessions (which auth() is just a wrapper around a session() call to get the user), is to use the following method:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    protected $user;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
           $this->user= auth()->user();

           return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Then `$this->user` will reference the `auth` user to any methods inside of this controller.

Hopefully his helps.

Comment: Thanks! Please, where do I put the code? Can it just be place like that in the class definition? Into constructor?

Comment: @PeterMatisko Sorry about that, I was moving too swiftly. It's been updated.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the question/title clear? Meaybe other people fight with something similar.

Comment: @PeterMatisko I think it's less about dependency injection and more about why the session isn't available in the class constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use base controller with `__get()` [method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). For example:

```
class Controller
{
    public function __get(string $name)
    {
        if($name === 'user'){
            return Auth::user();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And in the child controllers can call `$this->user`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.6 i used this

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $res = $this->validateAnyFunction($id);
        if(!$res){
        //to redirect to any other route
            return $next(redirect()->route("any")->with("failed","Invalid")->send());
        }
        //this is used to proccess futher funcitons of controller
        return $next($request);
    });
```